# How to add HTML content in a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a json file from which HTML content is fetched and displayed on the browser

```
"content": "Hello World <h1 class=\"page-title\">H1 Heading HTML tag</h1> <p>Para Tag</p>",
```

This works when HTML content is small.

How should I handle large HTML blocks of content such as a slider or accordian. Is it possible to call a file instead of the content.

Thanks

Comment: *"Is it possible to call a file instead of the content."* Of course, it's better not to put HTML content into json, just load it directly.

Comment: What happens with large content?

Comment: what do you mean by _HTML content is fetched and displayed_ ?? do you  want to get chunk to content not entire file content?

Comment: I think you don't understand, what is the purpose of using JSON.

Comment: content can be anything, an image, chunk of text, text which needs to be displayed in two columns, a slider or an accordion

Comment: You can offcourse use json to fetch particular html contents and not the entire file as you are saying.What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing `html` , [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)

html

```
// e.g., "/path/to/html/"
<div id="first">Hello World 1 <h1 class="page-title">H1 Heading HTML tag</h1> <p>Para Tag</p></div>
<div class="second">Hello World 2 <h1 class="page-title">H1 Heading HTML tag</h1> <p>Para Tag</p></div>
<img src="image-1">
<img src="image-2">
```

js

```
$("#container1").load("/path/to/html/ #first");
$("#container2").load("/path/to/html/ .second");
$("#container3").load("/path/to/html/ [src=image-1]");
$("#container4").load("/path/to/html/ img:eq(1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. load div content like a below code.

```
$.get('json.JSON',function(result){
   //You will get the JSON data in result
   $("#container").html(result.content);            
});
```